# Facebook SDK 4.7 Login error handling

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, fbsdk

I added FBSDK 4.7 to my swift app and when it opens the safari view controller to login, and I try to tap "Done" without inputting anything into the email/password fields, the app breaks. It spits out `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

How do I handle this error?

Current login code:

```
if let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager(){
fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"],fromViewController:self,
handler:{(result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                print("Logged in successfully")
                self.getFBUserData()
                //fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
        else{
            print("HELPPPPPPPPPP")
        }   
     })
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to assign the types of variable `(result, error)` :

Here is working code with Facebook 4.7 SDK | Swift 2 | Xcode 7.

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil { //Here we have to check that the set contains value or not
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

We have to check the `grantedPermissions`'s `Set` is `nil` or not.

```
if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil { //Here we have to check that the set contains value or not
```

Comment: thanks for the insight on the login function. But even with this when I hit the button and the login manager comes up, if I do not input anything into email or password and hit the "X" button on the top left, it crashed the app and still says `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`